# Unable to start Fuchsia on emulator

Tags: fuchsia

I am trying to run Fuchsia on the built-in emulator by following the instructions [here](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/getting_started.md). In the section 'Boot from QEMU' when I try to start the OS on the emulator, I got following errors

```
Creating disk image...done
+ /home/.../fuchsia/prebuilt/third_party/aemu/linux-x64/emulator -feature VirtioInput,RefCountPipe,KVM,GLDirectMem,Vulkan -window-size 1280x800 -gpu host -fuchsia -kernel /home/rong.yang/workspace/Fuchsia/fuchsia/out/default/multiboot.bin -initrd /tmp/tmp.yqZ2cVWFXe/fuchsia-ssh.zbi -m 2048 -serial stdio -vga none -device virtio-keyboard-pci -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_1 -smp 4,threads=2 -machine q35 -device isa-debug-exit,iobase=0xf4,iosize=0x04 -enable-kvm -cpu host,migratable=no,+invtsc -net none -drive file=/tmp/tmp.yqZ2cVWFXe/fvm.blk,format=raw,if=none,id=vdisk -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=vdisk -append 'TERM=xterm-256color kernel.serial=legacy kernel.entropy-mixin=b0852a979ec7cacb7f117a86c50a6dadf88df6234890c08faecc766160c9806f kernel.halt-on-panic=true '
emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037
emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:496: Failed to create Vulkan instance.
Could not access KVM kernel module: Permission denied
qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize KVM: Permission denied
```

Any suggestions?

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: Try `chown root:kvm /dev/kvm`  It seems to be a problem with KVM permission

Comment: @HùngNguyễn, changing the ownership of the kvm fix the problem, thanks :)